# Where to put common user program data in Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10?

Tags: c#, windows

It may seem like this question has been asked a thousand times before, but I can't find an answer that actually points to a path that is **common AND writable** for **all** users.

In any case - in my application the users can download some fairly large data files that need to be accessible to the application after download. The application is used in multi user enviroments, so I'm not interested in storing a copy of the downloaded files for each user.

So far I've been using `CommonApplicationData` (`C:\ProgramData\[Vendor]\[Application]` created using Wix installer), but I've recently learned that this is meant as readonly storage and several users have experienced issues with this because `CommonApplicationData` is write protected.

I've been checking different options and the only viable one I have found so far is the `%public%` folder (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files/).

Is this the best/correct place to put the files or is there another solution? Needs to work in Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10.

Answer (score 1):

CommonApplicationData is indeed the correct place to store this data, unless the users should be able to see them as documents to double-click.

When you create the folder (or the individual files or subfolders within it) you should set the permissions according to your needs.

One alternative approach, to provide better cross-user security, is to install a system service to download and install these files on the users behalf.